# Understanding TCP Push operation

Tags: tcp, websocket

is Web Socket using TCP Push operation?
As Far as i have researched by googling is Web Socket uses Full Duplex TCP Connection ...[Web Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)
TCP also has a PUSH operation to send some data immediately without waiting in Queue 
For example ( source [Data Communications and Networking
 By Behrouz A. Forouzan](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=bwUNZvJbEeQC&pg=PA726&lpg=PA726&dq=The%20application%20program%20on%20one%20site%20wants%20to%20send%20a%20keystroke%20to%20the%20application%20at%20the%20other%20site%20and%20receive%20an%20immediate%20response&source=bl&ots=qsq2E1TvjG&sig=ti9uh12xLp-x2NIJQIlYU2-jyO8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIjIDvtOfSyAIVRpGOCh3X7wMj#v=onepage&q=The%20application%20program%20on%20one%20site%20wants%20to%20send%20a%20keystroke%20to%20the%20application%20at%20the%20other%20site%20and%20receive%20an%20immediate%20response&f=false))

> The application program on one site wants to send a keystroke to the
>   application at the other site and receive an immediate response.
>   TCP can handle such a situation. The application program at the
>   sending site can request a push operation. This means that the sending
>   TCP must not wait for the window to be filled. It must create a
>   segment and send it immediately. The sending TCP must also set the
>   push bit (PSH) to let the receiving TCP know that the segment includes
>   data that must be delivered to the receiving application program as
>   soon as possible and not to wait for more data to come.
>   Although the push operation can be requested by the application program, most
>   current implementations ignore such requests. TCP can choose whether or not to use
>   this feature.

Comment: The TCP PUSH flag is practically obsolete. It is usually ignored. Don't confuse it with the Web Socket PUSH operation.

Comment: I looked for the PUSH operation you mentioned in the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) but didn't found anything. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: What EJP means is that WebSockets allows sending data  to clients, without an actual client request this is called "push model". When the client has to do an actual request to get data from clients (like HTTP), that is called "pull model". Usually people talks about "push" when they are talking about WebSockets, however you are referring to an specific TCP concern with the same name.